# ValueError: Input 2 of layer "full_model" is incompatible with the layer when creating a multi-view Variational Autoencoder model using Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras, keras-layer

I want to implement a multi-view Variational Autoencoder (VAE) model using Keras. The

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

# Dummy data for transcriptomics
transcriptomics_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 100), index=[f'gene_{i}' for i in range(1, 11)],
                                   columns=[f'sample_{j}' for j in range(1, 101)])

# Dummy data for epigenomics
epigenomics_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(8, 100), index=[f'methyl_{i}' for i in range(1, 9)],
                                columns=[f'sample_{j}' for j in range(1, 101)])

# Dummy data for proteomics
proteomics_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 100), index=[f'protein_{i}' for i in range(1, 6)],
                               columns=[f'sample_{j}' for j in range(1, 101)])

# Dummy labels for survival and immune response
survival_labels = pd.Series(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100), name='Overall_Survival',
                            index=[f'sample_{j}' for j in range(1, 101)])
immune_labels = pd.Series(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=100), name='Immune_Response',
                          index=[f'sample_{j}' for j in range(1, 101)])

# Dummy data for mRNA deconvolution
mrna_deconv = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 10), index=[f'mrna_cell_type_{i}' for i in range(1, 6)],
                              columns=[f'sample_{j}' for j in range(1, 11)])

# Dummy data for methylation deconvolution
meth_deconv = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 8), index=[f'meth_cell_type_{i}' for i in range(1, 6)],
                               columns=[f'sample_{j}' for j in range(1, 9)])

common_index = set(transcriptomics_df.columns).intersection(epigenomics_df.columns, proteomics_df.columns, 
                                                            survival_labels.index, set(immune_labels.index), 
                                                            mrna_deconv.columns, meth_deconv.columns)

transcriptomics_df = transcriptomics_df.loc[:, transcriptomics_df.columns.isin(common_index)]
epigenomics_df = epigenomics_df.loc[:, epigenomics_df.columns.isin(common_index)]
proteomics_df = proteomics_df.loc[:, proteomics_df.columns.isin(common_index)]
survival_labels = survival_labels.loc[survival_labels.index.isin(common_index)]
immune_labels = immune_labels.loc[immune_labels.index.isin(common_index)]
mrna_deconv = mrna_deconv.loc[:, mrna_deconv.columns.isin(common_index)]
meth_deconv = meth_deconv.loc[:, meth_deconv.columns.isin(common_index)]

transcriptomics_deconv_df = pd.concat([transcriptomics_df, mrna_deconv], axis=0)
epigenomics_deconv_df = pd.concat([epigenomics_df, meth_deconv], axis=0)

# Create a dictionary to hold your dataframes
omics_data_dict = {
    "transcriptomics": transcriptomics_deconv_df.T,
    "epigenomics": epigenomics_deconv_df.T,
    "proteomics": proteomics_df.T,
}

# Multivariate
y = pd.concat([survival_labels, immune_labels], axis=1)

# Concatenate all views for each dataset
X = {key: omics_data_dict[key] for key in omics_data_dict.keys()}

# Split the data into train, test, and validation sets
train_ratio = 0.7
val_ratio = 0.15
test_ratio = 0.15

train_data_dict, val_data_dict, test_data_dict = {}, {}, {}

for key, data in X.items():
    X_train, X_temp, y_train, y_temp = train_test_split(data, y, test_size=1 - train_ratio, random_state=42)
    X_val, X_test, y_val, y_test = train_test_split(X_temp, y_temp, test_size=test_ratio/(test_ratio + val_ratio), random_state=42)

    train_data_dict[key] = (X_train, y_train)
    test_data_dict[key] = (X_test, y_test)
    val_data_dict[key] = (X_val, y_val)

# Concatenate all labels for each dataset
train_labels = {key: np.concatenate([train_data_dict[key][1] for key in train_data_dict.keys()]) for key in train_data_dict.keys()}
val_labels = {key: np.concatenate([val_data_dict[key][1] for key in val_data_dict.keys()]) for key in val_data_dict.keys()}
test_labels = {key: np.concatenate([test_data_dict[key][1] for key in test_data_dict.keys()]) for key in test_data_dict.keys()}


def create_vae(input_dim, latent_dim, learning_rate, num_classes, dropout_rate):
    # Encoder
    encoder_inputs = layers.Input(shape=(input_dim,), name='encoder_input')
    y_input = layers.Input(shape=(num_classes,), name='class_input')
    
    z = layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu')(encoder_inputs)
    z = layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(z)

    # Concatenate the encoded output with class labels
    z_with_class = layers.Concatenate(name='concat_layer')([z, y_input])

    # Decoder
    decoder_inputs = layers.Input(shape=(latent_dim + num_classes,), name='decoder_input')
    x_decoded = layers.Dense(input_dim, activation='sigmoid')(decoder_inputs)

    # Classification layer
    classification_layer = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='classification')(z_with_class)

    # Full model
    full_model = models.Model([encoder_inputs, y_input, decoder_inputs], [x_decoded, classification_layer], name='full_model')

    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        reconstruction_loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true[0], y_pred[0])
        classification_loss = tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y_true[1], y_pred[1])
        return reconstruction_loss + classification_loss

    full_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate), loss=custom_loss, metrics=['accuracy'])

    return full_model

# Arbitrary parameters
best_latent_dim = 2
best_learning_rate = 0.5
best_dropout_rate = 0.5
best_epochs = 2
best_batch_size = 2
best_num_classes = len(np.unique(train_labels))

# Create VAE models for each omics dataset
vae_models = {}

for key, (train_data, _) in train_data_dict.items():
    input_dim = train_data.T.shape[1]
    vae_models[key] = create_vae(input_dim=input_dim, latent_dim=best_latent_dim, 
                             learning_rate=best_learning_rate, 
                             num_classes=best_num_classes,
                             dropout_rate=best_dropout_rate)

# Train VAE models
for key in train_data_dict.keys():
    # Separate the inputs
    encoder_inputs = train_data_dict[key][0]
    y_input = train_data_dict[key][1]  # Use the key to index the correct labels
    decoder_inputs = train_data_dict[key][0]  # Use the same data for decoder inputs as encoder inputs
    
    # Ensure data shapes are consistent
    print(f"{key}: x shape={encoder_inputs.shape}, y shape={y_input.shape}")
    
    # Verify key matching between train_data_dict and vae_models
    assert key in vae_models, f"Key {key} not found in vae_models"
    
    # Fit the VAE model
    vae_models[key].fit(
        x=[encoder_inputs, y_input, decoder_inputs],
        y=[encoder_inputs, y_input],  # Adjust labels accordingly
        epochs=best_epochs,
        batch_size=best_batch_size,
        validation_data=(
            [val_data_dict[key][0].T, val_data_dict[key][0].T],  # Transpose validation data
            [val_data_dict[key][0].T, val_data_dict[key][0].T]  # Transpose validation data
        ),
        verbose=1
    )
```

Traceback:

```
transcriptomics: x shape=(5, 15), y shape=(5, 2)
Epoch 1/2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [227], in <cell line: 2>()
     16 assert key in vae_models, f"Key {key} not found in vae_models"
     18 # Fit the VAE model
---> 19 vae_models[key].fit(
     20     x=[encoder_inputs, y_input, decoder_inputs],
     21     y=[encoder_inputs, y_input],  # Adjust labels accordingly
     22     epochs=best_epochs,
     23     batch_size=best_batch_size,
     24     validation_data=(
     25         [val_data_dict[key][0].T, val_data_dict[key][0].T],  # Transpose validation data
     26         [val_data_dict[key][0].T, val_data_dict[key][0].T]  # Transpose validation data
     27     ),
     28     verbose=1
     29 )

File /scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File /local/scratch/melchua/slrmtmp.42333570/__autograph_generated_filegjukc1vd.py:15, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__train_function(iterator)
     13 try:
     14     do_return = True
---> 15     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16 except:
     17     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/scg/apps/software/jupyter/python_3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 2 of layer "full_model" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 3), found shape=(None, 15)
```

Input dimensions:

`X` is a dictionary of datasets, whereas `y` is a multivariate dataframe. `X` index corresponds to `y` index

```
len(X)
3

X['transcriptomics'].shape
(8, 15)

X['epigenomics'].shape
(8, 13)

X['proteomics'].shape
(8, 5)

y.shape
(8, 2)
```

Comment: Well you're using the same data for encoder and decoder inputs, but the decoder expects a different shape, of course that doesn't work.

Comment: @xdurch0 Thank you for your comment. I'm new to machine learning. So, should I use `decoder_inputs = layers.Input(shape=(input_dim,), name='encoder_input')` instead? Can you please post an answer with the necessary edits? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This crashes because you are giving the encoder inputs to the decoder, which doesn't make sense. There is no need to have any `decoder_inputs` at all if you are not planning to use the decoder separately. You can simply chain the encoder and decoder in your `create_vae` function:

```
x_decoded = layers.Dense(input_dim, activation='sigmoid')(z_with_class)
```

And then remove `decoder_inputs` completely.